# dataflow failed to set up worker

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

Tested my pipeline on DirectRunner and everything's working good. 
Now I want to run it on DataflowRunner. It doesn't work. It fails even  before enter my pipeline code, and I'm totally overwhelmed by the logs in stackdriver - just don't understand what they mean and really don't have any clue on what's wrong.

- execution graph looks loaded fine
- worker pool starts and 1 worker is trying to run through the setup process, however looks never success
- some logs that I guess might provide useful information for debugging:

  `AttributeError:'module' object has no attribute 'NativeSource'
  /usr/bin/python failed with exit status 1

  Back-off 20s restarting failed container=python pod=dataflow-fiona-backlog-clean-test2-06140817-1629-harness-3nxh_default(50a3915d6501a3ec74d6d385f70c8353)

  checking backoff for container "python" in pod "dataflow-fiona-backlog-clean-test2-06140817-1629-harness-3nxh"

  INFO SSH key is not a complete entry: .....`

  How should I tackle this problem?

**Edit:**
my setup.py here if it helps: (copyed from [[here]](http://beam/sdks/python/apache_beam/examples/complete/juliaset/setup.py), only modified`REQUIRED_PACKAGES`
 and `setuptools.setup` section)

```
from distutils.command.build import build as _build
import subprocess

import setuptools


# This class handles the pip install mechanism.
class build(_build):  # pylint: disable=invalid-name
  """A build command class that will be invoked during package install.

  The package built using the current setup.py will be staged and later
  installed in the worker using `pip install package'. This class will be
  instantiated during install for this specific scenario and will trigger
  running the custom commands specified.
  """
  sub_commands = _build.sub_commands + [('CustomCommands', None)]


# Some custom command to run during setup. The command is not essential for this
# workflow. It is used here as an example. Each command will spawn a child
# process. Typically, these commands will include steps to install non-Python
# packages. For instance, to install a C++-based library libjpeg62 the following
# two commands will have to be added:
#
#     ['apt-get', 'update'],
#     ['apt-get', '--assume-yes', install', 'libjpeg62'],
#
# First, note that there is no need to use the sudo command because the setup
# script runs with appropriate access.
# Second, if apt-get tool is used then the first command needs to be 'apt-get
# update' so the tool refreshes itself and initializes links to download
# repositories.  Without this initial step the other apt-get install commands
# will fail with package not found errors. Note also --assume-yes option which
# shortcuts the interactive confirmation.
#
# The output of custom commands (including failures) will be logged in the
# worker-startup log.
CUSTOM_COMMANDS = [
    ['echo', 'Custom command worked!']]


class CustomCommands(setuptools.Command):
  """A setuptools Command class able to run arbitrary commands."""

  def initialize_options(self):
    pass

  def finalize_options(self):
    pass

  def RunCustomCommand(self, command_list):
    print 'Running command: %s' % command_list
    p = subprocess.Popen(
        command_list,
        stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    # Can use communicate(input='y\n'.encode()) if the command run requires
    # some confirmation.
    stdout_data, _ = p.communicate()
    print 'Command output: %s' % stdout_data
    if p.returncode != 0:
      raise RuntimeError(
          'Command %s failed: exit code: %s' % (command_list, p.returncode))

  def run(self):
    for command in CUSTOM_COMMANDS:
      self.RunCustomCommand(command)


# Configure the required packages and scripts to install.
# Note that the Python Dataflow containers come with numpy already installed
# so this dependency will not trigger anything to be installed unless a version
# restriction is specified.
REQUIRED_PACKAGES = ['apache-beam==2.0.0',
                    'datalab==1.0.1',
                    'google-cloud==0.19.0',
                    'google-cloud-bigquery==0.22.1',
                    'google-cloud-core==0.22.1',
                    'google-cloud-dataflow==0.6.0',
                    'pandas==0.20.2']


setuptools.setup(
  name='geotab-backlog-dataflow',
  version='0.0.1',
  install_requires=REQUIRED_PACKAGES,
  packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
)
```

**worker-startup log:** and it ended at the following exception

```
I  /usr/bin/python failed with exit status 1 
I  /usr/bin/python failed with exit status 1 
I  AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'NativeSource' 
I      class ConcatSource(iobase.NativeSource): 
I    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_worker/concat_reader.py", line 26, in <module> 
I      from dataflow_worker import concat_reader 
I    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_worker/maptask.py", line 31, in <module> 
I      from dataflow_worker import maptask 
I    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_worker/executor.py", line 26, in <module> 
I      from dataflow_worker import executor 
I    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_worker/batchworker.py", line 63, in <module> 
I      from dataflow_worker import batchworker 
I    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_worker/start.py", line 26, in <module> 
I      exec code in run_globals 
I    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code 
I      "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name) 
I    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main 
I  AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'NativeSource' 
I      class ConcatSource(iobase.NativeSource):
```

Comment: Could you share a job ID? Within cloud logging there may also be additional information in some of the other logs (eg., worker, worker_startup, etc.) that may include a bit more detail about why the worker didn't startup.

Comment: @BenChambers JobID: 2017-06-13_14_00_46-14992846213167080594, 2017-06-14_08_17_20-10061999408051657645.   I can see an exception from worker-startup log. I added them into my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be using incompatible requirements in your `REQUIRED_PACKAGES` directive, i.e. you specify `"apache-beam==2.0.0"` and `"google-cloud-dataflow==0.6.0"`, which conflict with each other.  Can you try removing / uninstalling the `"apache-beam"` package and install / include the `"google-cloud-dataflow==2.0.0"` package instead?

Comment: It is really frustrating experience working on the dataflow. what works on my local runner might fail for reasons on Cloud runner.

Comment: It's really confusing (not your answer, but the document) Every Google document  for dataflow is saying that it's based off Apache Beam now and directs me to Beam website. Also, if I looked for github project, I would see the google dataflow project is empty and just all goes to apache beam repo.

Comment: does that mean google-cloud-dataflow is deprecated and I should install apache-beam instead ?  plus, I tried uninstalling apache-beam and keeping only google-cloud-dataflow, there's error from directrunner:    ImportError: No module named options.pipeline_options  .     seems like under google-cloud-dataflow, beam package is still on the older version but I just cannot find any supportive API document  from Google explaining the version pick.....

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  This is an important issue for us to fix and we're aware of the confusion this can cause.  We plan to solve this issue with our next release.